# Parse an XML string in MySQL

Tags: mysql, xml, xpath

I have a task of parsing a simple XML-formatted string in a MySQL stored procedure. XML looks like this (testing purposes only):

```
<parent>
    <child>Example 1</child>
    <child>Example 2</child>
</parent>
```

What I need MySQL to do is to produce a result set one row per match. My stored proc code looks like this:

```
DECLARE xmlDoc TEXT;
SET xmlDoc = '<parent><child>Example 1</child><child>Example 2</child></parent>';
SELECT ExtractValue(xmlDoc, '//child');
```

What this does, however, is it concatenate all the matches, producing "Example 1 Example 2". This is, by the way, documented, but quite useless behavior.

**What can I do to make it return the matches in rows** without having to count the matches and processing them one-by-one? Is it even possible with MySQL?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE count DEFAULT ExtractValue(xml, 'count(//child)');

WHILE i <= count DO
    SELECT ExtractValue(xml, '//child[$i]');
    SET i = i+1;
END WHILE
```

Alternatively...

```
DECLARE v VARCHAR(500) DEFAULT '';
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;

REPEAT
    SET v = ExtractValue(xml, '//child[$i]')
    SET i = i+1;
    IF v IS NOT NULL THEN
        -- do something with v
    END IF
UNTIL v IS NULL
```

Sorry if the syntax is a bit shakey in here, not much of a mysql guru...

Answer (score 8):

This needs a rowset generation function, and `MySQL` lacks it.

You can use a dummy table or a subquery instead:

```
SELECT  ExtractValue(@xml, '//mychild[$@r]'),
        @r := @r + 1
FROM    (
        SELECT  @r := 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  1
        ) vars
```

Note that support for session variables in `XPath` is broken in `5.2` (but works fine in `5.1`)

Comment: Using this query I only get two rows. Am I missing something?

Comment: @reticent: as was told before, `MySQL` lacks a rowset generation function. The subquery only returns 2 rows which is what you get. Add more rows into `vars` (or replace it with a `SELECT` from a table large enough).

Answer (score 1):

Below is a stored procedure example to read xml using a while loop

```
-- drop procedure testabk;
-- call testabk();
delimiter //
create procedure testabk()
begin

DECLARE k INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE xpath TEXT;
declare doc varchar(1000);
DECLARE row_count1 INT UNSIGNED; 

set doc='<StaticAttributesBM><AttributeId id="11">Status</AttributeId><AttributeId id="2">Reason</AttributeId><AttributeId id="3">User Remarks</AttributeId></StaticAttributesBM>';
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tempStaticKeywords;
CREATE TABLE tempStaticKeywords(id int, staticKeywords VARCHAR(500));
SET row_count1 := extractValue(doc,'count(/StaticAttributesBM/AttributeId)');
select row_count1;

-- iterate over books
WHILE k < row_count1 DO        
    SET k := k + 1;
    SET xpath := concat('/StaticAttributesBM/AttributeId[', k, ']');
    INSERT INTO tempStaticKeywords(id,staticKeywords) VALUES (
      extractValue(doc, concat(xpath,'/@id')),
      extractValue(doc, xpath)     
    );
END WHILE;

select * from tempStaticKeywords;

END
//
```

**Output is below**

id  staticKeywords

1   Status

2   Reason

3   User Remarks