# How to search children nodes in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Lets say I have a table called Tags with an id columnm name column, and a parent_id column. Many tags are nested using the parent_id column. How would I check if Tag A has Tag B as a non-direct child efficiently.

Previously I have selected all tags that have a parent_id of the current tag and then got the result and repeated for any child elements.

How would I do this more efficiently to get all tags that match a search and is a direct or non-direct child.

Thanks for the help,
Jason

Comment: You'll want to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query

Comment: @DanK beat me to that, but if you can't restructure your table structure, there are not many better options than what you are already doing.

Comment: Maybe these would be useful for you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/902678/parse-an-xml-string-in-mysql http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/xml-functions.html. (I've always done XML parsing in PHP).

Comment: @DanK I can structure the database differently if I need to. Just to make sure, this has the capability of a dynamic number of layers of children? Thanks!

Comment: No the levels are hardcoded and not a true recursive query. I work more with Oracle and SQL Server where recursive queries are possible but according to this post MySQL doesn't offer this functionality: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46127/recursive-self-joins

Comment: @DanK That's a bummer. In the link it mentions some workarounds, one being an adjacency list. Does that sound like a solution? I'm guessing the Oracle and SQL Server are paid software? Thanks

Comment: @JasonGallavin the highest voted answer on the question DanK linked supports indefinite layers. The only downside is that when a child is added, much of the tree must be updated as well. Edit: I should point out I am talking about the "Nested Set" model.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than discuss in the comments... here is what I would recommend:

- If you want to stick with MySQL but can play with the structure of your database then absolutely this "[Closure Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192220/what-is-the-most-efficient-elegant-way-to-parse-a-flat-table-into-a-tree/)" pattern suggested by Bill Karwin is the way to go. It allows you to keep your data in a flat table design while abstracting the multi-level tree structure into a separate table for easy data extraction.
- If you want to try a different Relational Database System then you might try [SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx) which is free from Microsoft. In full disclosure, I don't use this so I don't know what functionality is excluded (and I'm sure something is otherwise you wouldn't get it for free). So please do some research to make sure `Recursive` [`Common Table Expressions`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL#Common_table_expression) (`CTEs`) are available. If they are then you can use Pinal Dave's [blog post](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/04/24/sql-server-introduction-to-hierarchical-query-using-a-recursive-cte-a-primer/) for recursive SQL technique using CTEs.
- Otherwise if you only think you will only ever have a handful of levels to work with, you can use the [original suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query) and hardcode the number of  levels.